# Only getting 2 tokens per line from strtok()

Tags: c

I'm trying to make tokens from an input file. So, I get one line with fgets and feed it to a helper method that takes in a char* and returns a char* of the token. I am utilizing strtok() with delimiter as " " since the tokens are all separated by " ". But, I can't figure out why the code only makes 2 tokens per line and just moves on to the next line even though there is more in that line needed to be tokenized. Here is the code:

```
char *TKGetNextToken( char * start ) {
    /* fill in your code here */
    printf("Entered TKGetNextToken \n");
    printf(&start[0]);
    char* temp = &start[0];

    //Delimiters for the tokens
    const char* delim = " ";

    //store tempToken
    char* tempTok = strtok(temp, delim);

    //return the token
    return tempTok;
}
```

Here is how I'm storing the tokens in the main method:

```
//call get next token and get the token and store into temptok
    while (temp!= NULL) {
        tempTok = TKGetNextToken(temp);
        printf("tempTok: %s\n",tempTok);
        token.charPtr[tempNum] = tempTok;
        tempNum++;
        printf("Temp:  %s\n",tempTok);
        temp = strtok(NULL, " \0\n");
    }
```

So, lets say I have a file.txt with:

```
abcd ef ghij asf32
fsadf ads adf
```

The tokens created would be "abcd" and "ef" and it will go on to the next line without making tokens for "ghij" and "asf32".

Comment: Note: C does not support _methods_, only _functions_.

Comment: And `printf(&start[0]);` is a clear no-go! **Never** pass usafe data as format-string! That is one of the most typical malware entry points (and the easiest to avoid).

Comment: You are calling `strtok` on the same string in both the function and the caller. Well, sort of. It's actually a mixture of NULL and non-NULL `strtok` calls on the same string. Which is even worse. That is almost certainly not what you want. To see what is happening in more detail suggest you use a debugger.

Comment: You're close to a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but you're missing some of the important code in `main`. Posting a MCVE makes the question easier to answer. That said, the answer will be to remove the `TKGetNextToken` function entirely, so you need to explain why that function exists, and why it's useful.

Answer (score 3):

Use the proper syntax for `strtok`

```
        char *tempTok = strtok(line, " "); //initialize
        while (tempTok != NULL) {
            //do the work
            tempTok = strtok(NULL, " \n"); //update
        }
```

If you do like above, then you can get the tokens quite easy. Please have a look at this example, which is similar to your code, just remember how you use [`strtok`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) properly, then it will work. Look at `strtok` and how it is used in the loop, updating and consumes the `char *`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    char line[256];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
        char *tempTok = strtok(line, " ");
        while (tempTok != NULL) {
            printf("token %s\n", tempTok);
            tempTok = strtok(NULL, " \n");
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0; 
}
```

File data.txt

```
abcd ef ghij asf32
fsadf ads adf
```

Output

```
./a.out 
token abcd
token ef
token ghij
token asf32

token fsadf
token ads
token adf
```

Comment: I would also remove the `\0` from the delimiter list. For two reasons. (1) `strtok` will always stop at the `\0` anyways, because that's the end of the string. (2) When you put a `\0` in the delimiter, everything after that will be ignored, because the `\0` terminates the delimiter list. That's why you got a blank line after the `asf32`: the `\n` in the delimiter was ignored.